# Get variables from list in another method?

Tags: c#, list, variables

I'm writing a webcam app and I need to write and read about 15 variables. I have two forms, the main window and the options window. When I save my options I do something like this:

```
string[] lines = {x , y, ..., z  };

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"config.cfg", lines);
```

In my main window I read the variables using the StreamReader function:

```
public void Foo()
{

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());

        reader.Close();
    }

    x = Convert.ToInt32(lines[0]);
    y = Covert.ToString(lines[1]);
    // and so on...
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to access `x` and `y` in another method. Btw: I declared all my variables as public static. Can anyone please help?

**Edit**

It is a windows forms app, the two windows do not exist at the same time. Maybe someone can give me a hint how to store those variables using a different method? The only thing I know I could do is store the vars using a MySQL database, but doesn't make much sense.

I'll try to clarify: what I would like to do, is pass `x` and `y` from the method `Foo` to another method. I can't use global variables, because reading the variables from the file requires a method.

Comment: Where are you declaring x and y? why not declare `string[] lines` as public static?

Comment: would setting x and y as viewstates help? or maybe your line array save in viewstate

Comment: Well, I don't know how to start answering your question. You're doing it all wrong, yet it will be hard to explain to you...

Comment: It IS a webcam app. However, is this winform or web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use properties=> setting to save your values if you will need it the next time.
it's simple and help you to avoid some problems

Comment: Ok, found a tutorial on CodeProject and helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do both forms exist at the same time? i.e in skype you have your main skype window and your chat windows?

If so just make a CameraUpdated event, which sends the lines changed to any subscribers, then that way you can just get your main window to bind to any new child windows events, so it will be notified.

To do this you would need to make a custom event arg to pass the data, a delegate for the event name and args, and expose the actual event on your form.

If however only one form exists at a time, you could either have an in memory store you push data to and then read it out of (much like your current implementation), or when you flip from one form to the other you pass in the data that has changed.

Ultimately I would try to avoid having global style data, be it in a file, memory or a global program variable, and opt for some loosely coupled approach, but without knowing your actual implementation its difficult to advise a specific solution.

Comment: The two forms may exist at the same time, but then the camera stream is off. The settings are applied when the stream is turned back on (the variables are supposed to hold fps values etc). If could show me another way of writing/reading variables I would be gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Class members that are declared as `public static` are accessible with:

```
ClassName.MemberName
```